# How to make an eloquent query on database two dimensional array by an one dimensional array value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

On my database I have a JSON array column(values) where my data is like:

```
{1:[1],2:[6]}
```

and my requested array is like:

```
$request['query'] = [1,6];
```

those are the values of nested array to filter down.

I can make query on one dimensional array on database like this:

```
 if (count($request['query']) > 0)
 {
   foreach ($request['query'] as $value) 
   {
      $products->orWhere('values', 'like', "%\"{$value}\"%");
    }
 }
```

where my database column(values) array was like:

```
[1,2]
```

Now I want to filter if any of my requested value get matched with my database nested array value.
Please help me out on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter data by an one dimensional array value using **whereIn()**

```
$query = Product::where('color', 'blue')
->whereIn('value', $request['query'])
->get();
```